# How to create a query that only populates data with dates in the AH column that are within the last 7 days

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to create a query that pulls our activation's (Column AH = activation date) for the past 7 days. How do I build this formula?

I tried guessing at the formula below but it is not working

```
=QUERY(DATA!1:1000, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, P, AH, AJ WHERE AH > ((Today()-7) AND B <> 'Rep'",1)
```

The below formula works for pulling data with a date (value) in column AH but I only want to see dates within the last 7 days

```
=QUERY(DATA!1:1000, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, P, AH, AJ WHERE AH is not null AND B <> 'Rep'",1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY(DATA!1:1000, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,P,AH,AJ 
  where AH is not null 
  and B <> 'Rep'
  and AH <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  and AH >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)
```